# Fetching DOM elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I am complete beginner in JS, so pardon my ignorance. I also didn't manage to find the answer to my question, although, undoubtedly, someone must have asked it before... so I'm posting here.

Here is a simple form I wrote:

```
    <head>
        <title>wowzy</title>
        <link href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>
       <form name="forma" id="prvaForma" action="/nonsense.php" method="POST">
           <label for="first">1st Value</label>
           <input id="first" type="text" name="firstField" value="1st Value here" onClick = 'check();'>
           <label for="second">2nd Value</label>
           <input id="second" type="text" name="2ndField" value="2nd Value here">
           <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT!">
       </form>
    </body>
```

and here is the JS function inside the scripts tag following the body

```
function check() {
    var v1 = document.body.prvaForma.first.value;
    alert("this is the value: " + v1);
}
```

Now, this doesn't work and I have been told what to do to make it work, e.g.

```
var v1 = document.getElementById("first").value
```

however, I would like to know why does it not work. I just imagined the DOM model in my head, and contructed the path that leads toward the element I want to select, i.e.

```
document.body.prvaForma.first.value
```

You can clearly see the DOM hierarchy here, and in the end, selecting the member "value" of the element.

I've been mostly programming in MATLAB and C, and I have some OO background in C++. JS seems awfully confusing right now, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't work because 'first' is the `id` of that element. Use the `name` like in: `var v1 = document.body.prvaForma.firstField.value;`

Comment: The dot notation you are trying to use (document.body.prvaForma.first.value) does not address how to access the DOM as it's not a simple variable tree like an Object.  You have to use the getElementByID in order to grab the element by a recognizable reference that the DOM can latch onto.

Comment: You're using the old "DOM Level 0" or "Legacy DOM" notation.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp but I thought JS references elements by their ID? Where does the name attribute comes into play?

Comment: Name comes from `name="firstField"`...

Comment: @MarcellFülöp yeah, I got that :D But **why** does it work with the "name" attribute, and it doesn't with the ID?

Comment: Because that's how it was agreed upon when the specification was written. But as @j08691 mentioned, this is an old DOM standard...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just imagined the DOM model in my head, and constructed the path that
>   leads toward the element I want to select, i.e.
>
> ```
> document.body.prvaForma.first.value
> ```

But DOM nodes do not have properties on them that match such paths! They only would collide with regular properties.

DOM nodes do have properties that allow them to access parent and child nodes (which builds up the DOM tree), and they do store some information about the node itself (tagname, attributes such as `id` or `class`).

Usually, you would use methods on them to find nodes in the tree, the most prominent of which is by using DOM selectors (you know them from CSS). Including shortcut methods like `getElementById` or `getElementsByClassName`.

And then there are some shortcut properties on the nodes, like `.children` which yields a collection of all element-typed child nodes. Similarly, there is a `.body` shortcut on the `document` which accesses the `<body>` node in the document. But these are exceptions!

The exception you might be looking for is the [`.forms` collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.forms), which holds all the `<form>` elements in a document by their name (attribute). And each form has an [`.elements` collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.elements), which holds inputs in that formular by their name (attribute). So you might use

```
document.forms["forma"].elements["firstField"]
```

but accessing the input by its `id` is much cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer!

One more reason I thought I could acess the input like I tried, is because I saw [something similar here.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_form_validations.htm)

 In particular, I saw this condition in the "if" branch:

    "if( document.myForm.Name.value == "" )"

, so I thought he is was accessing this value in the same way I I tried, but failed. Can you, perhaps, find the difference between his way and my way?

Comment: OKay, just to update, the thing I noticed now is that the article is using the name atributes and not the ID's while referencing the elements! So I guess that's why it works, great, but it just confuses me more...

Comment: Yes, Internet Explorer did introduce the quirks that you could access elements by their name directly on the `document` object (`document["forma"]["firstField"]`), and other browsers did copy this behaviour to be compatible. However, it remains quirks, is errorprone, and should not be used. Don't read any articles that are as old as that.

Comment: Yes, those `.forms[]` and `.elements[]` are by the `name` of the element (and not necessarily unique). Using `document.getElementById("first")` is better.

Answer (score 0):

As you are taking your first steps in JS, I recommend using the developer [console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console) to debug and explore the language. Open in with the F12 key.

Now, being specific to your question, take a look at the documentation of [document.forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.forms), you might find it useful to select values inside forms.

Comment: Yeah, I am yet to get comfortable using the console. :D

I'll study the link above in more detail when I find the time, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is what DOM level 0 looks like (DOM2 and 3 are almost identical) - http://www.technologyuk.net/the_internet/web/document_object_model.shtml

So to access your form items you would use

```
var ele = document.forms['prvaForma'].elements;
var val = ele['firstField'].value
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. If I can ask one more question, tho, if you google images for DOM model, you essentially get two different graphs, like [the one you posted](http://www.technologyuk.net/the_internet/web/images/dom_level0.gif), and, for example, [this one](http://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_htmltree.gif).

I was using the latter one, I guess, and also thinking that I can use ID's as a way to identify individual elements.

Is there a way to establish the connection between these two charts? And which one is **THE** DOM model chart?

Comment: @Lajka some graphs shows the DOM levels other show the tree structure of elements within a page.

Comment: Yeah, so I guess, my question is, do these models constitute together this "DOM model" thingy, or what? For example, why can't i find the body element on the chart you posted? Just trying to connect these charts in my head.